# Visual Studio 2013 not attaching to a browser process for javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

I have visual studio 2013 running on two machines. I used to be able to do javascript debugging on both machines. For some reason, one of the machines no long hits javascript breakpoints and it doesn't seem to be attached to ie process because when I close the browser, debugging session doesn't stop, I'd have to manually stop it. I've tried my best to compare the configurations of both machines and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC or RAZR and your JS is in your cs/html file, this can cause the debugging issues.  It's a known bug for the Visual Studio 2013 team that they're working on and should go into an upcoming update (it may have even been the most recent update, I haven't checked it yet).

A workaround is supposed to be taking your JS and placing it in a separate file.

See [Visual Studio 2013 can't debug javascript in cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807845/visual-studio-2013-cant-debug-javascript-in-cshtml) for more information.