# Visual Studio 2013 can't debug javascript in cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I have an ASP.NET Web Application created with Visual Studio 2013.  I am attempting to debug JavaScript in a CSHTML file.  However, whenever I launch the webpage, any breakpoint turns into a red circle arrow and states, "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.  Possible causes include: conditional compiliation, compilier optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type."

Recently, the project was switched over to support MVC and RAZR, neither of which I know well, and this is exactly when this issue began.  However, searching those have yielded results that don't fix my issue.

Web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true"...>
```

I know I can debug JavaScript with Firebug or some other browser tool, but I would much rather stick with Visual Studio's debug as that is what I am used to.

Comment: Have you edited the view or added the breakpoint after you started debugging? Try stopping your debugging session, save your view if it has outstanding changes, make sure your breakpoint is in place - then start the debugging session again.

Comment: No, I have not.  This happens with every break point I have, even one left for several fresh debugging sessions.

Comment: @pwdst Any other ideas?  Do you know if debugging JavaScript in Visual Studio is possible?

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer is installed on the computer? I believe Visual Studio 2013 uses the Trident engine from Internet Explorer 11 for debugging - so that would need to be installed (it should be upgraded with the Visual Studio installation, but it's possible you or an admin have since downgraded for corporate policy reasons). Also make sure you don't try and debug (inspect by all means, but don't debug) in Internet Explorer at the same time as each will attempt to attach the debugger to the same process.

Comment: Also, how are you adding the script(s) to the page? Can you debug scripts in an unchanged new template MVC application?

Comment: IE Version is 11.0.9600.  I knew about not debugging from IE at the same time, although admittedly only because it warned me that another debugger was already attached.

I'm adding the scripts via a <script type="text/javascript"> block in the cshtml file.

I'll try debugging an unchanged new template MVC application now.

Comment: @pwdst I get the exact same warning with an unchanged new template MVC application as described above.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

So, apparently this is a "known issue" that will be fixed as soon as possible.  A temporary work around that works for "some" people is making sure any Javascript is in a separate file.

It is caused by having RAZR and Javascript in the same file and Visual Studio 2013 not being able to handle debugging in that instance.

Comment: Can you share any references for this being a known issue?

Comment: I'll see what I can do, as it was e-mail support.  I've sent an e-mail off to them requesting references.

Comment: This probably saved me years of googling. Posts like this should get way more up votes vs. posts about - whats the best way to use a string.

Comment: For reference, I still haven't heard back from them about a reference to where they list their known issues.  I just pinged them again.

Comment: here is the bug report filed with miscrosoft  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807088/unable-to-debug-javascript-from-the-vs-2013-ide-unable-to-set

Comment: What is odd here is that debugging is fine if in a js file or when an js exception is thrown inside a cshtml file and you select break in vs. Also, if you set a break in a js file and the logic flows over into js in a cshtml then the debugger will continue with no problem.

Comment: This issue appears to be fixed in VS2013 Update 2.

Comment: @LeeGrissom Not for me, I just duplicated this problem in VS2013 update 2 with a .vbhtml page

Comment: Update 2 had fixed it although I did need to add BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false; before I could debug

Comment: If I stick a "debugger" statement, in the .cshtml javascript, the debugger breaks at that point, and then I can step through the code, and can even add additional breakpoints with the mouse.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know what your particular problem is, but if you want to force a debug breakpoint to always happen, add `debugger;` to the line that you want it to stop on, and it will stop.  This is regardless of where the JS is located (in a .js file, .html, cshtml, etc.)

Here is a blog post about it:

http://sumitmaitra.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/quickbytes-visual-studio-2013-and-javascript-debugging/

I also agree that JS should go in a .js file (which I've never had a problem adding a break point in a .js file), but for quick prototyping, this is a solution you can use.

If that still doesn't work, you can always you the F12 tools

Comment: No, it does not stop even with `debugger;`.  As soon as I run the app, the debug break point changes to a red arrow circling itself, and has the warning above for a tooltip.  It also skips over the break point just fine (i.e. I call functions from the web page that have break points, and they work without stopping at the break points).

I have separated the javascript into a separate file, and the same behavior persists.

Comment: That is very strange.  Have you tried attaching the F12 tools' debugger to see if it will break in there?  If it doesn't break in F12 tools, then I would suspect maybe the browser is at fault?

Comment: Trying to attach the F12 tool's debugger throws an error: The script debugger failed to connect to the target process.  A debugger is already attached.

Comment: Ok, start the web app w/o debugger attached (ctrl+F5) and then try to attach the F12 tools

Comment: browser could be caching the JS. Make sure you Ctrl+F5 if you change anything. adding the explicit `debugger;` line will not add a red circle breakpoint, but it should force either VS to break, or the IE debugger will.

Comment: Using debugger helped me.

Answer (score 12):

The only browser that allows debugging a javascript file from Visual Studio is Internet Explorer. (this is what I found out after testing my application on different browsers)

Comment: Why is that? I see a lot of posts around saying that but no explanation as to why...

Comment: I really do not know. Maybe because: Internet Explorer is Microsoft - made. Visual Studio is also Microsoft made. I do not have a better idea :(

Comment: Isn't this outdated since VS 2015 or so?

Answer (score 5):

I put my javascript in a separate file and debug with IE otherwise it will not work.

For some reason chrome doesnt allow you to step into the javascript.

Answer (score 5):

One additional thing to check. If you have a App_Start|BundleConfig.cs (which came with MVC 4 - or maybe 3), set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations to false (or, like I did, wrap it in an #if !DEBUG #endif and take the default setting).

Comment: Took me a good hour to figure out this was the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and failed to use Chrome and then IE and ended up using the Firebug addon in Firefox, and I was able to debug and set breakpoints in my JS with no problems (in an MVC6 app on Visual Studio 2015 where this is apparently still an issue?!)...

FYI - When I tried to debug my JS in Chrome using the F12 Developer Tools, it told me it was not an option as the Debugger was already attached to another process...

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here in 2017, I want to share that **I had this same issue** with **VS2017 Enterprise RC**, and with **VS 2015 Community** with **any browser but Internet Explorer**. Using IE did the trick for me.

Also, in VS2017, **I had to add a** `debugger` **statement to get VS start looking at debug points**.

Finally, I'd like to ask at least a comment from people voting down.

Comment: VS 2017 does not want to stop on JS breakpoints inside a .cshtml file for me either regardless of browser. Move the code to JS file and all is fine.